# Java - Console-like web applet

Tags: java, api, console, applet

Hey, I've been developing an application in the windows console with Java, and want to put it online in all of its console-graphics-glory.

Is there a simple web applet API I can use to port my app over?

I'm just using basic System.out and System.in functionality, but I'm happy to rebuild my I/O wrappers.

I think something along these lines would be a great asset to any beginning Java developers who want to put their work online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just make into an applet, put a small swing UI on it with a JFrame with two components - one for writing output to, and one for entering inputs from. Embed the applet in the page.

Answer (score 4):

I did as [Lars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138157/java-console-like-web-app#138206) suggested and wrote my own.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Applet extends JFrame {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    /** Text area for console output. */
    protected JTextArea textArea;

    /** Text box for user input. */
    protected JTextField textBox;

    /** "GO" button, in case they don't know to hit enter. */
    protected JButton goButton;

    protected PrintStream printStream;
    protected BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    /**
     * This function is called when they hit ENTER or click GO.
     */
    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            goButton.setEnabled(false);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        String userInput = textBox.getText();
                        printStream.println("> "+userInput);
                        Input.inString = userInput;
                        textBox.setText("");
                        goButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }   
            );
        }
    };

    public void println(final String string) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    printStream.println(string);
                }
            }   
        );
    }

    public void printmsg(final String string) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    printStream.print(string);
                }
            }   
        );
    }

    public Applet() throws IOException {
        super("My Applet Title");

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        textArea = new JTextArea(30, 60);
        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        final JScrollBar jScrollBar = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
        contentPane.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, jScrollPane);
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        textArea.setAutoscrolls(true);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 14));

        // TODO This might be overkill
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    jScrollBar.setValue(jScrollBar.getMaximum());
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            }
        }.start();

        JPanel panel;
        contentPane.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel = new JPanel());

        panel.add(textBox = new JTextField(55));
        textBox.addActionListener(actionListener);

        panel.add(goButton = new JButton("GO"));
        goButton.addActionListener(actionListener);

        pack();

        // End of GUI stuff

        PipedInputStream inputStream;
        PipedOutputStream outputStream;

        inputStream = new PipedInputStream();
        outputStream = new PipedOutputStream(inputStream);

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "ISO8859_1"));
        printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        textArea.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioException) {
                    textArea.append("ERROR");
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

This below code was in a separate class, "Input", which has a static "inString" string.

```
    public static String getString() {
        inString = "";

        // Wait for input
        while (inString == "") {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        return inString;
    }
```

Through-out the lifespan of the project I will probably maintain this code some more, but at this point - it works :)

Answer (score 3):

As a premier example of a glorious and incredibly useful cnsole-like webapp, please see [goosh](http://goosh.org), the Google Shell. I cannot imagine browsing the Net without it anymore.

Granted, there's no source code, but you might get out a bit of its magic by using Firebug or so.

Using a TextArea might be a bug-prone approach. Remember that you'll need to do both input and output to this TextArea and that you must thus keep track of cursor position. I would suggest that, if you really do this approach, you abstract away over a plain TextArea (inheritance, maybe?) and use a component that has, e.g. a `prompt()` to show the prompt and enable input and a also follows the usual shell abstraction of having `stdin` (an InputStream, that reads from the prompt, but can be bound to, let's say files or so) and `stdout` and possibly `stderr`, OutputStreams, bound to the TextArea's text.

It's not an easy task, and I don't know of any library to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seenig telnet client applet implementationa around years ago (back when people used telnet). Maybe you could dig them out and modify them.

Answer (score 0):

System.out and System.in are statics and therefore evil. You'll need to go through your program replacing them with non-statics ("parameterise from above"). From an applet you can't use System.setOut/setErr/setIn.

Then you're pretty much sorted. An applet. Add a TextArea (or equivalent). Append output to the text area. Write key strokes to the input. Job done.

Comment: I only use System.in and System.out in my IO class wrapper - So that won't take too long.

So I suppose the answer is just to use a TextArea. Thanks!